# SharePoint 2013 CSOM C# - How to limit results of KeywordQuery to specific folder?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, csom, keywordquery, kql

I am currently using SharePoint 2013. I want to limit my results of the query to specific folder within my list.

For example entering the oath for the QueryText field:

```
keywordQuery.QueryText = "path: https://fakesite.com/sites/appdev/Shared Documents/a_folder/another_folder/target_folder"
```

I know that path points to an .aspx for the list (from my little understanding), but is their a way to specify what folders in the list I want to narrow my results to?

Thank You for any help...this has been bugging me.